# Cache busting specific modules with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, requirejs, browser-cache

This question has been asked several times but not specific to this example.

Here is an overview of our application:

- Simple server routing with Express on Node
- Single page backbone application
- Core modules and libraries (JS/CSS) that don't change
- Widget JS/LESS/HTML files that frequently change

During development, I am looking to cache bust files that change but not those core libraries to speed up my page reloads and quicken my development.

I have found explanations on:

1. Cache Busting on RequireJS - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts)
2. Explanation on Cache Busting Specific Modules - [here](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/468#issuecomment-12126496)

Could the solution:

1. Explain how the requireJS caching busting works?
2. Provide a solution for this specific scenario.

Answer (score 4):

The cache-busting works by appending an always-unique query string to the end of every file which is required.  It makes use of RequireJS's `urlArgs` config value; RequireJS takes care of appending it for you:

```
urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
```

The`(new Date()).getTime()` part is just a simple way to get a unique string out of JavaScript.  You could do some variation on `Math.random()`, but using the [number of milliseconds since the epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221297/706561) guarantees uniqueness, for optimum cache-bustage.

I think Mr Burke is suggesting something like:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base/path',
    paths: {
        'fileAlias': 'fileLikelyToChange?bust=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
        'anotherFileAlias': 'anotherFileLikelyToChange?bust=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
        'jQuery': 'jQuery'
    },
});
```

So, instead of the ubiquitous `urlArgs` cache-busting, you apply it specifically to each file which is likely to change; hence, excluding any libraries.

I haven't tested it, but I'd probably tidy it up to something like:

```
function bust(path) {
    return path + '?bust=' + (new Date()).getTime();
}

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base/path',
    paths: {
        'fileAlias': bust('fileLikelyToChange'),
        'anotherFileAlias': bust('anotherFileLikelyToChange'),
        'jQuery': 'jQuery'
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks - what about files that are included throughout my application but not referenced in the require.config - paths object?

Comment: For that scenario, I don't think there is an easy solution.  I'm just describing what I think was suggested in the GitHub issue.  I don't think you really have any other options, short of modifying RequireJS's source or making an elaborate hack.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that if you really need to rely on some external script that you can use [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) instead of require to ensure that it's included. I have some non-amd scripts that are for 3rd party integration (e.g. amazon payments), which I used getScript for instead of require. If you can use this method, it would avoid sending the cache busting parameters from urlArgs to the external server.