# RequireJS data-main with query string not working

Tags: javascript, requirejs

To avoid the browser caching my optimised JS bundle, I'd like to include an MD5 sum on the request URL. I tried something like:

```
<script src="lib/require.js" data-main="app/main.js?md5=ABCD"></script>
```

However the introduction of the query string causes a GET request to `/main.js`. That is, the query string is missing and even `scripts` is missing from the path.

How can I force the request for the script specified in `data-main` to be loaded with the hash that I've calculated? Note that the markup is being generated, so I can inject the hash anywhere in the HTML document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent RequireJS from Caching Required Scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts)

Comment: @kryger, I used that technique in the past to avoid caching issues on non-main scripts. However that config doesn't effect the loading of the script from `data-main` unless you include it directly in the HTML such that it's executed before the RequireJS script kicks off. This question is related, but subtly different, and indeed I read that other question before asking this one. Hopefully this helps out someone else too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use the `urlArgs` configuration setting. So, in this example the code should resemble:

```html
<script>
require = {
    urlArgs: 'md5=ABCD'
};
</script>
<script src="lib/require.js" data-main="app/main.js"></script>
```

Make sure you define the global `require` object *before* loading the `require.js` library.

This works because RequireJS runs the following code when it starts up (as of v2.1.10, see line 190 of the unminified source):

```
//Allow for a require config object
if (typeof require !== 'undefined' && !isFunction(require)) {
    //assume it is a config object.
    cfg = require;
    require = undefined;
}
```

Check your browser's dev tools and you should see the the arguments on the query string:

[image]

Comment: The issue with this is the data-main is loaded asynchronously, while you are loading the urlArgs synchronously. Although a slim chance main.js will load BEFORE that config is set, it's still a hard coded assumption. I'd still like to know how to get the querystring args from data-main :(

Comment: @TruMan1, you're right. I've updated my answer with code that removes the race condition.