# Asset building with fingerprinting for pure JavaScript RequireJS app?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, asset-pipeline, fingerprinting

I'm building a pure JavaScript application using RequireJS, Backbone, Marionette, Handlebars, Underscore, and all that great stuff.

For now, I have it plugged into a Rails app, and I build the app (minify, concatenate, and MD5 fingerprint files) using the Asset Pipeline and [requirejs-rails](https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails) (and FWIW, I'm using [this fork](https://github.com/scalient/requirejs-rails) with Rails 4). I'm only using Rails because of the Asset Pipeline's [fingerprinting feature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#main-features) for cache-busting purposes...otherwise, I'd use straight r.js.

Are there any alternatives to doing fingerprinting in conjunction with RequireJS builds, without relying on Rails? Maybe some plugin to, fork of, or command option to r.js?

I also need the ability to build and fingerprint CSS files and images.

Comment: see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8479953/742624), which utilizes the [`urlArgs` option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs) of RequireJS.