# Why isn't my most up to date console.log message showing when main.js in Requirejs is updated

Tags: requirejs

I am learning RequireJS and confused about why my most up to date console.log message doesn't show on the page unless the close the page down and open it up again.

This is my set up:

index.html page which links to require.js:

```
<script data-main="main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

This is the code in my main.js:

```
define(function(){
    console.log("Hello World");
});
```

Initially, when I open up index.html the console will show the correct message. Now, when I update *console.log("Hello World")* to *console.log("Hello Universe")*, I expect the console in index.html, on refresh, to show "Hello Universe".

Thanks

Comment: Use a debugger (e.g. Firebug) to see what gets loaded, I mean the actual code. The browser is probably loading the old version for some reason. Possible reasons (not exclusive list): (1) Caching (either the browser decides to cache or your server instructs the browser to cache) (2) Server has not finished deploying the new version of your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this thread [Prevent RequireJS from Caching Required Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts)

RequireJS was doing some sort of a caching and to prevent this (at least whilst am developing) is this bit of script in my index.html

```
<script>
    require.config({
        urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Note that it's not actually RequireJS doing the caching but your browser. An alternative could be to disable browser cache or install some "clear the cache" plugin.