# How to automatically add md5 signature in require('index.js') when using gulp,browserify,angular

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browserify

everyone, I'm working on my project with gulp, browserify, angular,but I run into a stone wall. I have wrote the code

```
var indexController = require('./controllers/index.js');
```

when I modify the controller file "index.js", and rebuild the project, the final javascript in browser is just still not refreshed.

So I search the way how to automatically add md5 signature after the require:

```
var indexController = require('./controllers/index.js?v=324975934795');
```

just like when working in html:

```
<script src="./controllers/index.js?v=324975934795"></script>
```

Also, I want to find a tool to help me automatically finish it.

I should appreciate it if anyone who suggest me a tool or show me how to automatically do the job.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts). I'd check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts), it seems to be most appropriate for your case.

Comment: Thank you very much.Requirejs is very nice, but I don't like the configuration of requirejs, so I use the browserify. Also, what I need is the solution in browserify.I have just found the tool on github to solve my problem.[node-static-asset](https://github.com/bminer/node-static-asset)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for anyone who checking.I have found the solution for my problem in [node-static-asset](https://github.com/bminer/node-static-asset) 
I should be glad if anyone who show me more nicer solution.