# Firefox and RequireJS still pulling from cache even with toolbox open

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, requirejs, firefox-developer-edition

I'm using FirefoxDeveloperEdition 36 on OSX 10.10.1.  I've enabled the "Disable Cache (when toolbox is open)" option in the toolbox's settings panel:

[image: Disable Cache (when toolbox is open) is enabled]

However, I'm not seeing my changes until I manually clear the cache via **Preferences** => **Privacy** => **clear your recent history**, even if I have the toolbox open.

I'm using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load my script dependencies.  [It looks like other people have had issues with RequireJS and caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts), so I'm guessing this is the root issue.

Is this option not working as promised, or am I doing something wrong?  I'd like to avoid the [`urlArgs` workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8479953/1063392) if possible.

I haven't noticed this behavior in any other browser.

Comment: That option is a client side issue, perhaps you have a server side issue with cache.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm working directly off a local install of Apache, so I would be surprised if the caching is happening server-side.  I'm also not seeing this behavior in any other browser.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing with cocos2d-js, which does javascript resource loading similar to RequireJS (as far as I can tell)

Comment: I have the same issue with client HTML templates. Definitely Firefox Developer Edition issue. Gone back to normal Firefox with Firebug... :(

Comment: Happens to me as well with text resources (templates) and RequireJS, Firefox 36 (Not developer edition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1129806

Be sure to upgrade to the latest Firefox release, as some aspects of the bug have been fixed already.

Comment: Just a note: still not fixed with version 48. Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651268/firefox-and-requirejs-still-pulling-from-cache-even-with-toolbox-open).