# RequireJS should make a new request always

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In my code I am doing a require call inside a function. How to make a fresh request every time I make the function call?

```
function test(){
 require(['scriptpath'], function(App){
  console.log(App);
 });
}

test();
test();
test();
```

Comment: Does the script change for each call?  Why is that if so?  If so this may not be the solution, you may need to embed the script otherwise.

Comment: Explore this questions options perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts

Comment: it is against all require() idea, but you can add cachebuster (like `+ '?=' + MATH.random()`) to your scriptpath and do such requsts. which probably will make memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that RequireJS modules are singletons, and *this is by design*. Even if you play with `urlArgs` to add a parameter to bust the cache, you won't get the result you want. When you call `test` the first time, RequireJS does not have the module already loaded so it fetches it. Then when you call it again, it sees that `scriptpath` is already loaded *and immediately calls the callback*. See, it won't go into your configuration and look at `urlArgs` or `paths` or anything else. If the module is already loaded, that's the end of the story: the callback is called immediately.

You may be able to get the result you want by doing something *similar* to cache busting. I've been able to cause RequireJS to load the "same" module by doing something like this:

```
var times = 0;
function test() {
  times++;
  require(["foo.js?" + times], function () {
    console.log("got foo");
  });
}
```

The code above uses a different module name for each `require` call, and thus RequireJS will issue a new request for each `require` call.

You cannot just use `Date.now()` to tack on at the end of the module name because two calls to `test()` may get the same value from `Date.now()` because they happen faster than the resolution of the timer and this will result in a single network query. That's why I use the variable `times` instead.