# React App with PWA - Changes are not showing after deployment until hard refresh of the pages

Tags: reactjs, caching, progressive-web-apps

We are using React Js and implemented PWA(Progressive Web App) using service workers. After each deployment to the server, the pages are not updated and we need to do hard refresh everytime. This is not the right way since we cannot inform the real time users to do hard refresh after each deployment. So please please solution on how to avoid hard refresh on react app with PWA

Comment: What you are looking for is a solution called **Cache Busting**.  See the following questions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts/8479953

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force browser to clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache)